# event system optimization

Tags: c++, templates

If I have these declarations and definitions:

```
enum Events
{
  INIT,
  RENDER
};

struct EventBase
{
  typedef void (EventBase::*event_callback_type)();

  ~EventBase() {}

  virtual void init() { assert(0); }
  virtual void render() { assert(0); }
};

template <enum Events>
struct EventTraits
{
  static EventBase::event_callback_type const event_callback;
};

// in a .cpp file
template <>
EventBase::event_callback_type const
EventTraits<INIT>::event_callback(
  &EventBase::init);

template <>
EventBase::event_callback_type const
EventTraits<RENDER>::event_callback(
  &EventBase::render);

// in another class *i are pointers to objects that inherit EventBase
template <enum Events event>
inline void EventNotifier::notify()
{
  for (events_type::const_iterator i(event_handlers[event].begin());
    i != event_handlers[event].begin() + num_event_handlers[event];
    ++i)
  {
    ((*i)->*EventTraits<event>::event_callback)();

    if ((*i)->num_event_handlers[event])
    {
      (*i)->notify<event>();
    }
    // else do nothing
  }
}
```

Say, that the event RENDER needs fastest possible handling, do you think it is worthwhile to do a member template specialization:

```
template <>
inline void EventNotifier::notify<RENDER>()
{
  for (events_type::const_iterator i(event_handlers[RENDER].begin());
    i != event_handlers[RENDER].begin() + num_event_handlers[RENDER];
    ++i)
  {
    (*i)->render();

    if ((*i)->num_event_handlers[RENDER])
    {
      (*i)->notify<RENDER>();
    }
    // else do nothing
  }
}
```

This would not require the fetching of a static pointer to a member function. Or perhaps I should do this:

```
template <enum Events>
struct EventTraits
{
  static EventBase::event_callback_type event_callback();
};
```

And specialize the struct template?

Comment: The only real way to know is to try it: compile it with you compiler, and profile (time) your program as it runs. Compilers do weird and wonderful things inside them as even your own CPU doesn't blindly execute the instructions it gets given so often what you think must logically be happening underneath you code, isn't.

Comment: What is your target architecture? This is important as it affects load hit stalls and branch prediction timings etc. Some compilers have profile guided optimisations which if enabled might get you your speed ups.

Comment: It is armv7, with neon extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just additional 5 cents. EventNotifier::notify() looks completely thread-unsafe. Futhermore, if any event handler generates new event bad things can happen. I suggest doing notification this way (C++ 11, just don't know all of your types):

```
template <> inline void EventNotifier::notify<RENDER>()
{
  decltype(event_handlers[RENDER]) local;
  decltype(num_event_handlers[RENDER]) local_num;

  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(my_mutex);
    local = event_handlers[RENDER];
    local_num = num_event_handlers[RENDER];
  }

  for (events_type::const_iterator i(local.begin()); i != local.begin() + local_num; ++i)
  {
    (*i)->render();

    if ((*i)->num_event_handlers[RENDER]) (*i)->notify<RENDER>();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am hunting for speed and locking kills it. The event handler just calls it's "children", so that the event is propagated. Say, you call `application->notify<RENDER>();` and all the children will be notified to render.

Comment: then its better to remove the condition i != event_handlers[RENDER].begin() + num_event_handlers[RENDER]; from the loop, and check with .end()

Comment: event_handlers[RENDER] is a std::array, not a std::vector. Speed is of the essence.

Comment: good, but why to do this arithmetic in the loop if it is constant?

Comment: What really matters for speed is the size of this array/vector. Yes, excessive locking kills the performance, but do you really need to send the RENDER event to all of your thousand objects ? Isn't it only the higher-level manager which is the receiver of this event ?

Comment: @SergeyK.: You think I should make a copy on the stack of the num_event_handlers?

Comment: There are 2 options: process events under lock or make a local copy and process it without lock. You can go the first way if you are sure that no handler will generate additional events.

Comment: @ViktorLatypov: The idea is, then when the application needs to render, everything that needs to render renders. So the event is propagated to all objects that aren't "hidden". For the high-level manager you need to explicitly bind a signal to a handler, but here no binding is done, the events are "generic", need to be handled always.

Comment: OK, you didn't tell if your actual object::render() handlers are lightweight. I.e., they might just enqueue the renderops. Then the system-wide render() can be viable but still I think it is slower than direct iteration of objects to render in a centralized manager.

Comment: @ViktorLatypov: Parent-child relationship needs to be maintained. How to do it in a central manager? You need a tree data structure, that you need to traverse and do a great deal of bookkeeping. You can avoid recursion, though.

Answer (score 1):

The member specialisation won't make any difference in it's current form as the code you have written in identical to the code the compiler will generate for you.

Here's a small improvement:

```
template <enum Events event>
inline void EventNotifier::notify()
{
  for (events_type::const_iterator i(event_handlers[event].begin()),
       end (event_handlers[event].begin() + num_event_handlers[event]);
       i != end; ++i)
  {
    ((*i)->*EventTraits<event>::event_callback)();

    if ((*i)->num_event_handlers[event])
    {
      (*i)->notify<event>();
    }
    // else do nothing
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Are you certain about what you say? In the specialization I am not referring to a static member and it does not need to be fetched.

Comment: Ah didn't spot the `(*i)->render()`. Which in retrospect is the main point of your question.